# What are the relevant adjectives for the noun, "Paradise"?

Tags: vocabulary

In my religion it is believed that Staff of Moses came on the earth from Paradise. My question is, what is the adjective of the word Paradise? Like something that belongs to the world is called worldly, one from earth is called earthly.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, that would be [**paradisiacal**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/paradisiacal) or [**paradisal**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/paradisal):

> *adjective*
>
> of, like, or befitting paradise.

But I can't say that these two words by any means are common.

Example sentence (you can find other examples on the  two pages I provided above):

> Whatever the causes were, the earth has returned to **paradisiacal** conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I would first ask where you are getting the word "paradise" from - is this a translation of a word you use in your faith?

In most Abrahamic faiths (Judaism, Christianity, Islam) the distinction between physical and spiritual realms are described as *heaven* and *earth*, so the adjectives to describe things from each of these would be "*heavenly*" and "*earthly*". The word "wordly" carries a slightly different meaning to "earthly". "Earth" is the name for our planet and so usually describes the *place* we live; the "world" more often describes Earth *and the people in it*, and so "wordly" tends to describe something or someone that has seen or been exposed to a lot of human experience.

The word "paradise" in English is used to describe different things in different faiths. In Christianity, it is not *usually* used to describe heaven. The original garden of Eden on earth was described as a paradise, and the term is used secularly to describe "perfect", untouched parts of Earth today. In Islam though, "paradise" is the word in English used to describe an "afterlife" for humans which I understand is said to be not of this world, so I would assume it is "heavenly".

I don't believe the adjectives "paradisaic" or "paradisaical" are what you are looking for, as these describe something that is *like* paradise, not *from* it. Although "Paradise" in certain faiths may refer to a specific place, by the rules of English it really refers to a *condition*, which is why there is no adjective to say that something or someone is *from* there. By comparison, an ancient Graeco-Roman name for heaven "Elysium" is sometimes translated as "paradise", and because Elysium is the *name* of a *specific* paradise, something or someone from Elysium is described as "Elysian". An example of this in French is the Parisian street *Avenue des Champs-Élysées*, which means *Elysian fields*.

If you are trying to say that something has come from heaven, I suspect the word you need is "heavenly". If on the other hand you believe that this "paradise" was a place on earth, is there a specific name for that paradise? For example, if you believe it was the Garden of Eden then it would be "*Edenic*".

Comment: So you mean that the apt word for the unseen place believed to be inhabited with souls after they leave the world is 'heaven'?

Answer (score 1):

The adjective **heavenly** is the proper counterpart to **worldly**.

Another possibility to consider, though not as an adjective for the Staff of Moses, is **unworldly**.

> The celibate ascetics  in the desert lived unworldly lives.

It refers to a retreat from society and its daily concerns, and from bodily needs.

The adjective **otherworldly** refers to the spiritual realm.

The adjective **divine** means "godly" or "pertaining to (a) god" or "belonging to (a) god".

The adjective **God-given** refers to that which has been given by God.